# Redux - Data not updating in Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I'm having trouble passing some data fetched via axios into the Redux store to be used on another component. I have other actions and reducers that are very similar and are working, but this one isn't.

The dataflow is as follows:

1. Start in Filter component
2. componentDidMount fires and fetches data thru axios
3. updateInfo (action) is called to update Redux store with the response's data
4. This is where it acts incorrectly. It falls into the default switch case statement instead of UPDATE_APPT_LIST action.
5. Info component console logs props but only the other reducers can be found.

```
// actions/index.js
export const UPDATE_APPT_LIST = "UPDATE_APPT_LIST" 

export const updateInfo = list => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_APPT_LIST,
        list
    }
}
```

```
// reducers/index.js
import { UPDATE_APPT_LIST } from '../actions'

const updateInfoReducer = (list = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_APPT_LIST:
            return action.list;
        default:
            return list;
    }
}
```

```
// Filter.js
class Filter extends React.Component {
    state = { info: [] }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.retrieveInfo()
    }

    retrieveInfo = async () => {
        let res = await axios.get('someURL')
        updateInfo(res.data)  // update redux store function
        this.setState({ info: res.data })
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { infoList: updateInfoReducer }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateInfo })(Filter)
```

```
// Info.js
class Info extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (... some jsx)
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Info)
```

Comment: can you check if   `case UPDATE_APPT_LIST:` is getting called by doing a `console.log(action)` underneath the case.

Comment: let me know what you get in the `console.log`

Comment: @BARNOWL it does not get called under that case. Rather the console.log gets called under default.

Comment: if i come up with a possible solution ill post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and it's a silly one. I forgot `const { updateInfo } = this.props` in Filter.js. This would lead the action to be dispatched anyways but `action.type` did not match in the reducer, leading the default case to be fired.